# Use Retrofit to consume Server Sent Events

Tags: java, rest, retrofit

I am trying to consume a rest api [[1]](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/rest-api.html#get-v2-events) that sends server sent events to the client.
I am currently using retrofit from square  to consume this but I am not sure how to do it.
Can some one who has prior experience working with retrofit help ?
If not retrofit please suggest other Java libraries that can do that.

[1] https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/rest-api.html#get-v2-events

Answer (score 4):

I know that it is old question. But I didn't find a whole example and now try to provide it by my code. **We use only `retrofit` and `coroutines`**

1.In `retrofit API interface` need to add code. Pay attention what we use `@Streaming` and return type `Call<ResponseBody>`

```
@POST("/v1/calc/group-prices")
@Streaming
fun calculateGroupPrices(@Body listOptions: List<GroupCalculatorOptions>): Call<ResponseBody>
```

2.In your `repository` class need to add this code. Pay attention what we use `flow` and read a `stream`. To understand that a message with a payload has arrived, it must begin with `"data:"`

```
fun loadGroupDeliveryRateInfos(listOptions: List<GroupCalculatorOptions>) = flow {
        coroutineScope {
            val response = restApi.calculateGroupPrices(listOptions).execute()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val input = response.body()?.byteStream()?.bufferedReader() ?: throw Exception()
                try {
                    while (isActive) {
                        val line = input.readLine() ?: continue
                        if (line.startsWith("data:")) {
                            try {
                                val groupDeliveryRateInfo = gson.fromJson(
                                    line.substring(5).trim(),
                                    GroupDeliveryRateInfo::class.java
                                )
                                emit(groupDeliveryRateInfo)
                            } catch (e: Exception) {
                                e.printStackTrace()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    throw Exception(e)
                } finally {
                    input.close()
                }
            } else {
                throw HttpException(response)
            }
        }
    }
```

3.Final step we need to collect our data in `ViewModel`. We just need to call the method from `repository`

```
 repository.loadGroupDeliveryRateInfos(it.values.toList())
                .collect { info ->
                    handleGroupDeliveryRateInfo(info)
                }
```

> And that's all, no additional libraries are needed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this library : [oksee](https://github.com/heremaps/oksse).

> OkSse is an extension library for OkHttp to create a Server-Sent Event (SSE) client

As I experienced the same problem,from my research it is the best option for now, as Retrofit doesn't support it.

https://github.com/heremaps/oksse

Comment: PRoject seems dead-ish. Now there's: https://github.com/launchdarkly/okhttp-eventsource

Answer (score 1):

There's no real need to conflate Retrofit and SSE. Use retrofit to get an inputstream, then find (or write) an inputstream parser that chunks up the SSE events.

In retrofit I have this:

```java
public interface NotificationAPI {
    @GET("notifications/sse")
    Call<InputStream> getNotificationsStream(@retrofit2.http.Query("Last-Event-ID") String lastEventId);
}
```

I wrote a quick converter factory for `InputStream`:

```java
public class InputStreamConverterFactory extends Converter.Factory {

    private static class InputStreamConverter implements Converter<ResponseBody, InputStream> {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public InputStream convert(ResponseBody value) throws IOException {
            return value.byteStream();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public @Nullable
    Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        if (type.equals(InputStream.class)) {
            return new InputStreamConverter();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

My client code looks like this:

```java
var cinputStream = api.getNotificationsStream(null);
var inputStream = cinputStream.execute().body();
try(var sseStream = new MySSEStreamParser(inputStream)) {
   //handle the stream here...
}
```

---

There is an OkHttp SSE parser, which you probably could use. However:

- The OkHttp SSE code comes with threads. Chances are you'd want to bring your own threading model.
- The actual OkHttp SSE parser is an internal package. Which doesn't make it a great candidate for lifting.

Comment: Hi! Sorry, but I have same issue with retrofit. I found your solution, but I dont understand how it works? I cant found class SSEStreamParser. May be you have example on git? It will be great! Thanks!

Comment: We rolled our own parser, the spec is fairly simple, see: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/server-sent-events.html - you basically wrap with a `BufferedReader` and call `readLine()`, the syntax is mostly: `data: <message>`.

Having said that, I imagine someone already has a parser that you can re-use. Let me know if you find one!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly more updated approach that I just got working based on [this](https://medium.com/@manoel.al.amaro/understand-kotlin-flow-coroutines-by-implementing-server-side-sent-sse-9e190ff5f24f) blog. It uses Retrofit's `@Streaming` with a Kotlin flow and a buffered reader. The SseHeartbeatData is just the custom json payload that my sse endpoint returns.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson
import kotlinx.coroutines.coroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.isActive
import okhttp3.ResponseBody
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Streaming

interface NetworkService {
  @Streaming
  @GET("/network/sse/heartbeat")
  suspend fun getHeartbeat() : ResponseBody
}

data class SseHeartbeatData(val count: Int, val timestamp: Long, val requestId: String)

class SseRepository(private val networkService: NetworkService) {

fun getHeartbeat() = flow {
    coroutineScope {
        val gson = Gson()
        val inputReader = networkService.getHeartbeat().byteStream().bufferedReader()

        var event: String? = null
        var heartbeatData: SseHeartbeatData? = null

        while (isActive) {
            val line = inputReader.readLine()

            when {
                line.startsWith("event:") -> {
                    event = line.removePrefix("event:").trim()
                }
                line.startsWith("data:") -> {
                    val jsonString = line.removePrefix("data:").trim()

                    if (event == "heartbeat") {
                        heartbeatData = gson.fromJson(jsonString, SseHeartbeatData::class.java)
                    }

                    event = null
                }
                line.isEmpty() -> {
                    heartbeatData?.let {
                        emit(it)
                    }
                    heartbeatData = null
                }
            }
        }
        inputReader.close()
    }
}
```

}

You can then collect it inside a view model and handle exceptions as needed.

```
_sseJob = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        sseRepository.getHeartbeat().catch {
            Log.w("MainViewModel", it)
            _sseJob?.cancel()
            _uiState.value = SseNotActive
        }
            .collect {
            _uiState.value = SseActive(count = it.count)
        }
    }
```