# SSE Client Kotlin | Example to consume text/event-stream in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, okhttp, resteasy, server-sent-events

I want to listen to an URL, for Server Side Events. I get the ping and updated event with data tags

I was using retrofit and Kotlin for another HTTP resource.
Is there any example or library that will suit my stack?

I'm using Kotlin, Retrofit, and OkHttp. Is there any other library that I will need for my use case (consume a URL resource that produces org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)

Comment: FWIW see also the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126564/use-retrofit-to-consume-server-sent-events

Comment: See also https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1029

Comment: That being said, it looks at the moment the experimental okhttp-sse is the best we have, see https://github.com/heremaps/oksse/issues/32